# Accordion Using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a list that's holding a header and a sub link, as shown below.

```
    <li>
      <a href="#"> <i class="fa fa-cogs fa-fw"></i> <span>SETTINGS</span> </a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a>PFA Setup</a></li>
        <li><a>Fund Setup</a></li>
        <li><a>Fee Setup</a></li>
        <li><a>Payment Setup</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

Please, i want a solution whereby the SETTINGS menu is clicked, then it expands the sub-menu class using typescript. I really don't know how to get this done with typescript.

Thanks.

Comment: Any javascript / typescript attempt to show us?

Comment: @briosheje that's why i said "I really don't know how to get this done with typescript".

Comment: What you want to achieve with `typescript` sounds a bit weird. However, if typescript is what you want then typescript is what you get if you decide to use a frontend framework like `Angular`. You can have a look at [`ng-bootstrap's Accordion Example`](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/components/accordion/examples)

Comment: @MIchealDavid Stackoverflow is not exactly a coding service, the question by itself is too broad, there is no specific problem explained, that's why I'm asking. Check this for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Please specify at least whether there is any framework used (jQuery, angular, react, whatever), whether the solution is only accettable in typescript, whether typescript references jQuery typings... There is much to specificy to properly answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery supports this: [JQuery accordion](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/). What you should do is get a typed version of JQuery ([Typed JQuery definition](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/jquery)).
When you include the typed version of JQuery you should be able to call the accordion functions from your TypeScript code.

Answer (score 0):

You could hide the sub menu with a css class, then when you click the `<li>` which will activate the submenu use: `element.classList.toggle`

css

```
.hide {
    display:none;
}
```

script - assign a ID to your `<ul>` submenu

```
const toggleFunction = () => {
    var element = document.getElementById("id");
    element.classList.toggle("hide");
}
```